# Article use in "The injured men were sent to the hospital"

Tags: articles, adjectives

> The injured men were sent to the hospital.

Why is "the" used before "injured men"?

> The young boy was taken to a hospital immediately.

Why is "a" used before "hospital" here?

Comment: Yes, it's a valid sentence. If that's all you wanted to know, the question is Off Topic proofreading. The article in ***the** hospital* is often omitted in BrE, but rarely in AmE. We all use ***a*** sometimes, but not usually.

Comment: The young boy was taken to a hospital immediately. Why article "a" is used here?

Comment: How can we use "the injured men" sir? the injured is already an adjective it works as a noun in my sentence.  I am totally confused please clear my confusion.

Comment: Why we use "a"why can't we use "the?May I know please ?

Comment: The young boy was taken to a hospital immediately, What is the sense of article "a"here?  I mean to say,  why we use "a"here?

Comment: As I already said, there's a *tendency* for BrE to omit the article completely. Other than that, there's a *tendency* for all native speakers to use ***the*** if they're thinking of a *particular* hospital. Using ***a*** always implies that the speaker doesn't have a particular hospital in mind. And by further implication, that there are probably multiple *possible* hospitals for the context - the speaker just doesn't know (or care, or wish to identify) any hospital in particular.

Comment: But please don't "expand" your question in comments like this - unless you ***edit the question text*** to reflect these specific points, it will probably be closed as proofreading, per my first comment.

Comment: Okay,  sorry sir. This question was related to article , that's what I asked you.  I am sorry for that.

Comment: (few Anglophones today use "sir" in contexts like this). What you need to remember is that all these comments are potentially temporary (moderators might delete them at any time). You question will stand or fall based on the merits of the actual text - comments are normally only supposed to be posted to help the asker to improve or clarify that question text, which is all other users should be considering when deciding whether to closevote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Injured men were taken to the hospital.

That's a grammatically correct sentence.

> The injured men were taken to the hospital.

That's also a grammatically correct sentence.

---

The first sentence tells us that some men were hurt and brought to a hospital.

The second sentence tells us that some men were hurt and brought to a hospital.

There is not really any difference in meaning, but I'd expect to see the second sentence in some sort of larger context that tells us something about who these men are, or where they were hurt. For example:

- Ten firefighters were hurt battling the wildfires. The injured men were taken to the hospital.
- The rebels took on heavy casualties during the night. The injured men were taken to the hospital.
- Fear ran wild right after the bridge collapsed. The injured men were taken to the hospital.

The way you have listed them, though, as standalones, there's not really much else to say about the meaning of these particular sentences.

Comment: I think the question was edited significantly after you answered - it's now about "the hospital" versus "a hospital".

Comment: @ColleenV - I thought Fumble's comment addressed the article before _hospital_ pretty well, so I decided to concentrate on the first part of the question – that part that his comment didn't address. (By the way, speaking of articles, are you considering a run for moderator? I was hoping you'd throw **a** hat into **the** ring.) :^)

Comment: Ah, I was confused by the two quoted sentences in the question not matching yours. I thought about stepping up, but I don't feel that I could make the commitment in good conscience. My work load is very unpredictable and has deadlines of the "If this doesn't get done, it's curtains for the company!" sort :)

Comment: @ColleenV - That's why it's a team effort, because we can't all be there all of the time. I'd love to have you run, but I don't want to twist your arm. Either way, thanks for all your positive contributions of late. You'd make an excellent moderator, to be sure.